# QtCreator working directory for a custom project?

Tags: makefile, qt-creator

I'm trying to run a Makefile for building a kernel module in QtCreator. I can successfully invoke the make file from the command line.

[image]

My assumption was that this shouldn't be a problem to set also in QtCreator by defining the build step as a custom command `make`.

It seems however that QtCreator is introducing some other working paths instead.

[image]

As the showcase above points, both the working directory and the script absolute path are set to `/home/user/module` which is the path in which the correct Makefile resides.

However, QtCreator seems to be searching for the Makefile at `/home/user/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/Makefile: No such file or directory`.

Am I missing a setting somewhere or is this a bug?

Comment: Works here. Which version of Qt Creator is that?

Comment: `Qt Creator 4.2.0 (4.2.0)
Based on Qt 5.7.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit)
Built on Dec 9 2016 12:18:01
From revision 5071dd80cb`

What is yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `PWD` environment variable in your makefiles. This environment variable is updated only by a shell though, and custom process steps are not executed in a shell by default, but started directly as a child process. This means that `PWD` will stay as it is shown in the "Run Environment" section of the run configuration instead of being changed to the working directory of the step.

If your custom step depends on features of the shell, you should run it in a shell, i.e. set the "Command" to `/bin/sh` (or `/bin/bash` or whatever you prefer), and the "Arguments" to `-c make` (or whatever you need to pass to your preferred shell to execute a command).

[image]